# How to make Git log show all of today's commits?

Tags: git, git-log

I want to be able to see all of the commits I made today using `git log`. I came up with `git log --after="yesterday"`
However, that seems a little awkward to me, is there a simpler command to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Edit: Since this is the accepted answer I can't delete it, so I'm posting here @Simon's answer:

```
git log --since="6am"
```

And of course you can adjust the time to whatever is "morning" enough for you :)

Comment: This does not seem to work on git 1.5.6.5, FWIW. I know, old version and all, but I figure this might help someone. `git log --after="yesterday"` seems to come closest to correct, but it ends up including things that occurred yesterday along with things that occurred *after* yesterday.

Comment: For me: `git log --since="yesterday"` works well. Looks nice with `--pretty="oneline"` too... (git version 1.7.10)

Comment: --since and --after are synonyms, so the answer is suggesting the same thing that is in the question.  This will give give the last 24 hours of commits (hence @agentbanks217 problem with seeing commits from yesterday).  I have give a different answer below.

Comment: Also, times like `"06:00"` work, for those that don't like AM/PM

Comment: I had imagined this would work until 5:59am the following day. However, it only lists commits on the same day (i.e., it stops working at midnight)

Answer (score 73):

Maybe the best is to use

```
git log --since="6am"
```

You can adjust the time to your convenience ;)

Comment: Also add --all to see the log of all branches during the period

Comment: I voted for this one over the other as it appears to be several days earlier.

Answer (score 29):

To get commits from **all** of today ...

```
git log --since=midnight
```

Comment: This command will show commits from today midnight 12AM to 11:59PM right ?

Answer (score 27):

You can create alias to shorten this command

```
git config --global alias.today 'log --since=7am'
```

and then execute:

```
git today
```

Answer (score 9):

There are already several useful correct answers (e.g. `git log --since="6am"`) but it is odd that Git's special dates are missing from the documentation (at least googling ["yesterday" "noon" site:git-scm.com](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=+%22yesterday%22+%22noon%22+site:git-scm.com) returns no results).

There are ways to find out what's available, for example the answers to [Specification for syntax of git dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14023794/575530) are particularly useful. In one [Ryan O'Hara points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14025405/575530) that

`it seems to accept all formats that it can output, as described in the documentation for the --date option:`

> #### `--date=(relative|local|default|iso|rfc|short|raw)`
>
> Only takes effect for dates shown in human-readable format, such as when using
>   `--pretty`. `log.date` config variable sets a default value for log
>   command’s `--date` option.
>
> `--date=relative` shows dates relative to the current time, e.g. "2 hours ago".
>
> `--date=local` shows timestamps in user’s local timezone.
>
> `--date=iso` (or `--date=iso8601`) shows timestamps in ISO 8601 format.
>
> `--date=rfc` (or `--date=rfc2822`) shows timestamps in RFC 2822 format, often found in E-mail messages.
>
> `--date=short` shows only date but not time, in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.
>
> `--date=raw` shows the date in the internal raw git format `%s %z` format.
>
> `--date=default` shows timestamps in the original timezone (either committer’s or author’s).

My favourite answer there is [from me_and](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14047499/575530)  who directs us to [the git date.c class](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/date.c). Scan down that and you find this code (at the time of writing it is on line 925):

```c
static const struct special {
    const char *name;
    void (*fn)(struct tm *, struct tm *, int *);
} special[] = {
    { "yesterday", date_yesterday },
    { "noon", date_noon },
    { "midnight", date_midnight },
    { "tea", date_tea },
    { "PM", date_pm },
    { "AM", date_am },
    { "never", date_never },
    { "now", date_now },
    { NULL }
};
```

I'm definitely using `git log --before=tea`, though looking at the `date_tea` function I don't think they've read [Rupert Brooke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Old_Vicarage,_Grantchester):

```c
static void date_tea(struct tm *tm, struct tm *now, int *num)
{
    date_time(tm, now, 17);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Btw, this also works:
`git log --since=am`

Comment: Careful though, this is equivalent to `--since=noon`.