# Seeing all my git commits for the day

Tags: git

Is there a way to see all my git commits globally (**not just one repo**, **all** my repos on my computer) in one log?

*edit*: I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113425/how-to-make-git-log-show-all-of-todays-commits) on StackOverflow, I'm looking for that but for all of my repos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in git itself, no, since it operates at the level of the repository.

You probably want to look into something like [mr](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/mr/), which is a tool to work concurrently with multiple repositories at the same time.

Comment: This worked - I used `mr log --since="6am"` and got the results I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not without writing your own custom script. Git is designed to work with one repository at a time.