# Specification for syntax of git dates

Tags: git

Is there any specification for the syntax of dates passed
to git?  For example, what dates are accepted by the
"--before" option to "git rev-list"?

Assuming there is no such specification, is there any
way to get git to transform a date into a canonical
form, so that one can check that a given date string
is being interpreted as one expects?  (Update: I've
written a script to do this, which is available
[here](https://github.com/ruafozy/utils/blob/master/git-time-parse/git-time-parse).)

Informational note: date parsing seems to be implemented
in the file date.c, in the root of git's repository.
The "entry point" seems to be a function called
approxidate_careful.

Comment: Note: Git 2.2+ (Nov 2014) now has a `--date=iso-strict`: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26961655/6309)

Comment: Note parsing of date in order to decide between `dd/mm/yy` or `mm/dd/yy` has changed with Git .2.2.2 (January 2015). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28256582/6309).

Answer (score 6):

It’s not explicitly noted anywhere as far as I can tell, but it seems to accept all formats that it can output, as described in the documentation for the `--date` option:

> #### `--date=(relative|local|default|iso|rfc|short|raw)`
>
> Only takes effect for dates shown in human-readable format, such as when using
>   `--pretty`. `log.date` config variable sets a default value for log
>   command’s `--date` option.
>
> `--date=relative` shows dates relative to the current time, e.g. "2 hours ago".
>
> `--date=local` shows timestamps in user’s local timezone.
>
> `--date=iso` (or `--date=iso8601`) shows timestamps in ISO 8601 format.
>
> `--date=rfc` (or `--date=rfc2822`) shows timestamps in RFC 2822 format, often found in E-mail messages.
>
> `--date=short` shows only date but not time, in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.
>
> `--date=raw` shows the date in the internal raw git format `%s %z` format.
>
> `--date=default` shows timestamps in the original timezone (either committer’s or author’s).

Comment: thanks! the git docs and man pages imply this only affects dates that are _output_, but in practice it also affects input date parsing as well.

Answer (score 5):

As you already found out git is usually using approxidate for parsing all kind of times.
This allows you to write all kind of natural to crazy ways to specify a time.

This allows you to write things like “six minutes ago” or “last Tuesday” or even "tea time" and approxidate usually understands what you mean. I am not aware of any explicit documentation other than the source you already found.

A nice blog entry on that topic is http://www.alexpeattie.com/blog/working-with-dates-in-git/

Answer (score 2):

The real code is at https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/date.c#L717 and enumerates the available formats such as iso8601, rfc2822 and various short, local, raw, and default formats.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, Git isn't consistent about what date and time formats it accepts.  The internal, canonical format is a combination of the Unix timestamp (ie seconds since midnight 1 January 1970) and the timezone offset.

For specifying dates, that's somewhat hard to read.  I'd use Git's interpretation of [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for a format that's relatively easy to read and will always be unambiguous. Depending on the command you're using, you can often get this with `--date=iso` as [minitech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14025405/220155). It'll look something like `2012-12-26 23:17:23 +0000`.

(The `--date=rfc` version is similarly unambiguous in that it will only be interpreted the same way, but that includes the weekday. I personally object to having that  around, since it allows you to specify dates that look valid but where the day doesn't match the date, such as `Sun, 26 Dec 2012 01:02:03 +0000` [That's today, a Wednesday].)

For the formats that are, I believe, accepted everywhere, run [`git help commit-tree`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit-tree.html); that man page includes the following (I've slightly reformatted):

> #### Date formats
>
> The `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE`, `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` environment variables support the following date formats:
>
> - Git internal format: It is `<unix timestamp> <timezone offset>`, where `<unix timestamp>` is the number of seconds since the UNIX emoch. `<timezone offset>` is a positive or negative offset from UTC. For example CET (which is two hours ahead UTC) is `+0200`.
> - RFC 2822: The standard email format as described by [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822), for example `Thu, 07 Apr 2005 22:13:13 +0200`.
> - ISO 8601: Time and date specified by the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, for example `2005-04-07T22:13:13`. The parser accepts a space instead of the `T` character as well.
>
>   Note: In addition, the date part is accepted in the following formats: `YYYY.MM.DD`, `MM/DD/YYYY` and `DD.MM.YYYY`.

Some places use "approxidate" and as such are less fussy, as [michas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870481/michas) [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024118/220155).  If you fancy digging into this, the code is in Git's [`date.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/date.c) (that link via the [Working With Dates in Git](http://www.alexpeattie.com/blog/working-with-dates-in-git/) link michas posted). For example, the below is from [`git help revisions`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html):

> #### Specifying revisions
>
> …
>
> - `<refname>@{<date>}`, e.g. `master@{yesterday}`, `HEAD@{5 minutes ago}`: A ref followed the suffix `@` with a date specification enclosed in a brace pair (e.g. `{yesterday}`, `{1 month 2 weeks 3 days 1 hour 1 second ago}` or `{1979-02-26 18:30:00}) specifies the value of the ref at a prior point in time. …

Answer (score 1):

Note that the "`date=iso`" format isn't *exactly* [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).
See commit "[466fb67](https://github.com/git/git/commit/466fb6742d7fb7d3e6994b2d0d8db83a8786ebcf)" from [Beat Bolli (`bbolli`)](https://github.com/bbolli), for Git 2.2.0 (November 2014)

### pretty: provide a strict ISO 8601 date format

> Git's "ISO" date format does not really conform to the ISO 8601 standard due to small differences, and it cannot be parsed by ISO 8601-only parsers, e.g. those of XML toolchains.
>
> The output from "`--date=iso`" deviates from ISO 8601 in these ways:
>
> - a space instead of the `T` date/time delimiter
> - a space between time and time zone
> - no colon between hours and minutes of the time zone
>
> Add a strict ISO 8601 date format for displaying committer and author dates.
> Use the '`%aI`' and '`%cI`' format specifiers and add '`--date=iso-strict`' or '`--date=iso8601-strict`' date format names.
>
> See [this thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/255879%20and%20http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/52414/focus=52585) for discussion.

---

9 years after the patch above from 2014, you also have Git 2.40 (Q1 2023) which loosens date parsing heuristics for ISO 8061:

See [commit b56be49](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b56be49984de166db6270c59e83f89d3608ddc69) (11 Jan 2023) by [Đoàn Trần Công Danh (`sgn`)](https://github.com/sgn).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d2917b9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2917b9099629202da86a8b59fa9e19695c07ede), 21 Jan 2023)</sup>

> ### [`date.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b56be49984de166db6270c59e83f89d3608ddc69): allow ISO 8601 reduced precision times
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Pat LaVarre</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phil Hord</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Đoàn Trần Công Danh</sup>

> ISO 8601 permits "reduced precision" time representations to omit the seconds value or both the minutes and the seconds values.
> The abbreviate times could look like `17:45` or `1745` to omit the seconds, or simply as `17` to omit both the minutes and the seconds.
>
> `parse_date_basic` accepts the `17:45` format but it rejects the other two.
> **Change it to accept 4-digit and 2-digit time values when they follow a recognized date and a '`T`'**.
>
> Before this change:
>
> ```bash
> $ TZ=UTC test-tool date approxidate 2022-12-13T23:00 2022-12-13T2300 2022-12-13T23
> 2022-12-13T23:00 -> 2022-12-13 23:00:00 +0000
> 2022-12-13T2300 -> 2022-12-13 23:54:13 +0000
> 2022-12-13T23 -> 2022-12-13 23:54:13 +0000
> ```
>
> After this change:
>
> ```bash
> $ TZ=UTC helper/test-tool date approxidate 2022-12-13T23:00 2022-12-13T2300 2022-12-13T23 
> 2022-12-13T23:00 -> 2022-12-13 23:00:00 +0000 
> 2022-12-13T2300 -> 2022-12-13 23:00:00 +0000 
> 2022-12-13T23 -> 2022-12-13 23:00:00 +0000
> ```
>
> Note: ISO 8601 also allows reduced precision date strings such as "2022-12" and "2022".
> This patch does not attempt to address these.

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.2.2 (January 2015) brings a small improvement when trying to decide between `dd/mm/yy` or `mm/dd/yy`.

See [commit d372395](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d37239536ce960af9292fdf297e7c277303e95be) written by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff)

> #### approxidate: allow ISO-like dates far in the future
>
> When we are parsing approxidate strings and we find three numbers separate by one of "`:/-.`", we guess that it may be a date.
>   We feed the numbers to `match_multi_number`, which checks whether it makes sense as a date in various orderings (e.g., `dd/mm/yy` or `mm/dd/yy`, etc).
>
> One of the checks we do is to see whether it is a date more than 10 days in the future. This was added in [38035cf (date parsing: be friendlier to our European friends., 2006-04-05, Git 1.3.0)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/38035cf4a51c48cccf6c5e3977130261bc0c03a7), and lets us guess that if it is currently April 2014, then "`10/03/2014`" is probably March 10th, not October
>   3rd.
>
> This has a downside, though; **if you want to be overly generous with your "`--until`" date specification, we may wrongly parse "`2014-12-01`" as "`2014-01-12`"** (because the latter is an in-the-past date).
>   If the year is a future year (i.e., both are future dates), it gets even weirder. Due to the vagaries of approxidate, months *after* the current date
>   (no matter the year) get flipped, but ones before do not.
>
> This patch drops the "in the future" check for dates of this form, letting us treat them always as `yyyy-mm-dd`, even if they are in the future.
>   This does not affect the normal `dd/mm/yyyy` versus `mm/dd/yyyy` lookup, because this code path only kicks in when the first number is greater than 70
>   (i.e., it must be a year, and cannot be either a date or a month).
>
> The one possible casualty is that "`yyyy-dd-mm`" is less likely to be chosen over "`yyyy-mm-dd`". That's probably OK, though because:
>
> 1. The difference happens only when the date is in the future. Already we prefer `yyyy-mm-dd` for dates in the past.
> 2. It's unclear whether anybody even uses `yyyy-dd-mm` regularly. It does not appear in [lists of common date formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_representation_by_country) [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date).
> 3. Even if (2) is wrong, it is better to prefer ISO-like dates, as that is consistent with what we use elsewhere in git.

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.40 (Q1 2023) amend the default date format for `git log`... which is *not* the [RFC 2822 format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822):

See [commit 9deef08](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9deef088aec321e72955d6ededc9c9f62f083851) (15 Feb 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a7981d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7981d071792234e30d892f3c675df802538f443), 24 Feb 2023)</sup>

> ### [`rev-list`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9deef088aec321e72955d6ededc9c9f62f083851): clarify `git-log` default date format

> The documentation mistakenly said that the default format was similar to RFC 2822 format and tried to specify it by enumerating differences, which had two problems:
>
> - There are some more differences from the 2822 format that are not mentioned; worse yet
> - The default format is not modeled after RFC 2822 format at all.
>
> As can be seen in [f80cd78](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f80cd783c6f346388bbb0a6a15672be99a71f7ed) (`date.c`: add , 2005-05-06, Git v0.99 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f80cd783c6f346388bbb0a6a15672be99a71f7ed)) ([`date.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9deef088aec321e72955d6ededc9c9f62f083851/date.c): add "`show_date()`" function., 2005-05-06), it is a derivative of [`ctime(3)` format](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime).
>
> Stop saying that it is similar to RFC 2822, and rewrite the description to explain the format without requiring the reader to know any other format.

`rev-list-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9deef088aec321e72955d6ededc9c9f62f083851/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L1103-L1107):

> `--date=default` is the default format, and is based on ctime(3)
> output.
> It shows a single line with three-letter day of the week,
> three-letter month, day-of-month, hour-minute-seconds in "`HH:MM:SS`"
> format, followed by 4-digit year, plus timezone information, unless
> the local time zone is used, e.g. `Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 1970 +0000`.