# Use relative date with git clone --shallow-since

Tags: git

Can I use a **relative** date in [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)'s [`--shallow-since=<date>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---shallow-sinceltdategt) (e.g. sth like `one-year-ago`)?

Command substitution (like `$(one-year-ago-command)` in `bash` and `PowerShell` or `` `one-year-ago-command` `` in `bash`) is no real alternative as I'm using `cmd` and `for /f` is a pain in the a**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. It works with the same `<date>` formats you can pass to e.g. `git log --since=<date>`.

For example:

```
git clone --shallow-since="1 week ago" <url>
```

This works with Git version 2.20.1.

See also:

- [Is it possible to do a shallow git clone based on datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693820/is-it-possible-to-do-a-shallow-git-clone-based-on-datetime)
- [git log --since=<date> options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405844/git-log-since-date-options)
- [Specification for syntax of git dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023794/specification-for-syntax-of-git-dates)