# git log --since=<date> options

Tags: git

I'm currently learning Git by following the book "Pro Git".

In the book, when discussing different options for `git log --since=<date>`, the author said some of the potential options for the `<date>` are

```
git log --since=2.weeks
git log --since="2008-01-15"
git log --since="2 years 1 day 3 minutes"
```

I was wondering, where can I find a complete list of what I can use as a date format in the `--since=<date>` option?

I have looked at the [git log manpage on git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) as well as searched the git-scm.com but I can't find it.

Comment: Check out `man git log` on command line. It gives you every option you could possibly want, with descriptions.

Comment: People, you are not answering the question! The man page does NOT have this information ... and surprisingly, neither does `git rev-parse`, which is what is used underneath.

Comment: @o11c I'm looking for options that specify what kind of date format I can use e.g. I can use "2.weeks", but what else is available? Like you said, the `git log` manpage does not seem to have this information, so i was wondering where exact could I find it?

Comment: @CaptainAmerica That's quite different from how I read the origin question.

Comment: try using git GUI like source tree and git extension you can manage your git more efficient.

https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/
 https://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/

Comment: @jhpratt I'm very sorry that I didn't make my intend clear initially, I think the edit by Nick explained better than I did. Sorry

Comment: @CaptainAmerica The edit definitely makes it clearer. My new answer is what you're looking for (I hope!)

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is *no* actual documentation for this. In case the documentation ever gets outdated, the (scary) source code is https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/date.c

Comment: @jhpratt except that you're not supposed to actually answer when it's an exact duplicate, which this turns out to be

Comment: @o11c I guess its unfortunate that there is no documentation available. And Thanks for the source code link, I guess i will go through it when I'm brave enough lol

Comment: @CaptainAmerica even if you don't understand the *code*, you can try just looking at the string literals, then shoving them together to see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19742762/2718801).

It goes into good detail about the current and historical options. Particularly, formats can follow RFC2822, ISO8601, or have relative formats, which is what you had in your question.