# git log --since date string parsing

Tags: git

I was looking through some logs in a submodule today (somewhat furiously) and typed some errors into the dates in the command

```
git log --since="2019-12-31" --oneline | wc -l
      90
```

and instead of typing that I typed,

```
git log --since="2019-12=31" --oneline | wc -l
    2147
```

I was alarmed by the difference is count which is why I was able to notice the error immediately. However, I'm unclear as to what the behavior is in this case. Is this a bug or is this expected behavior for `git log`?

I would expect an error in parsing but it looks like the logs go back to January or February of 2019.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specification for syntax of git dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023794/specification-for-syntax-of-git-dates)

Comment: Did you check the actual output? Are you sure it isn't 2147 lines of "bad date" type errors?

Comment: @AdrianCornish: It's not that, git is actually outputting the history, I tried it.

Comment: @AdrianCornish the link does not answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that Git's date parsing just stops when it gets to a part it can't understand.  For example "2015-13" is understood as "2015", as is "2015-4444".

In your case, it's treating "2019-12=31" as "2019".  And then a second weird "feature" kicks in: `--since 2019` does not mean `--since 2019-01-01`, it means "since today's date in 2019".  So the meaning of your `--since 2019-12-31` will actually change throughout each year when you run it!

What seems to be happening is:

1. Generate the current date-time (in your time zone).
2. Replace the parts you specified in `--since`, ignoring the month and day part if the parser cannot decide how to parse it.

Note that even the simple and "obviously correct" `git log --since 2019-12-31` does not really do what one might expect, because it shows commits since the current time on that day, not since midnight.  So unless you specify a full date-time string, there will always be some dependency on the time when the command is executed.

Comment: thanks for clarifying and for the link to approxidate c code, very interesting! Marking as correct.