# git log --since is excluding the first commit

Tags: git, git-log

Suppose a git repo has 12 commits and 4 was created *yesterday* (let's say *December 31st, 2199*).

`git log --oneline` will output:

```sh
9675a65 fix: a bug in feature B
041e1b2 feat: add feature B
d0f58e3 refactor: apply DPs to feature A
e933840 feat: add feature A
a6a235d chore: update version
...

f982bfd chore: initial commit
```

#### Expected behavior

From my understanding, if I run `git log --since=1.day` today (*January  1st, 2200*) I should get an output including the last 4 commits from yesterday (in the example: from *feat: add feature A* to *fix: a bug in feature B*).

#### Actual behavior

But instead, I am getting only the last 3 commits (from *refactor: apply DPs to feature A* to *fix: a bug in feature B*). `git log --since=1.day` is not including the first commit created yesterday in its output (the *feat: add feature A*).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Watch out for time anomalies (time zone issues for instance, or the clock being wrong on some committer's computer) and note that "since" means *after* and "1.day.ago" means "24.hours.ago" which means "2073600 seconds ago". These are also applied to committer timestamps (there's no option to use author timestamps here).

Comment: @torek, I just checked the commit times and  It is about the *24.hours.ago*.  But is there an option to output all the commits created yesterday only? I tried `--before=2020-07-19 --after=2020-07-18`  but it still outputs like *24.hours.ago*.

Comment: I just figured it out that the flag `--after=2020-07-18-00:00:00` do this trick

Comment: @torek Do you want to post your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computer time is always more complicated than it looks.

In this case it appears it was just that you were thinking in terms of selecting commits from a particular day.  In Git, however, `--since` (or `--after`, which has the same meaning) computes an exact second:

```
--after=2020-07-18
```

means "after whatever time it is now, but on that day", and:

```
--after=1.day.ago
```

means "after 24 hours since *exactly* 1 day ago" or "subtract 86400 seconds from this second, and use that as the after value".  You can, as [you commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62983039/git-log-since-is-excluding-the-first-commit?noredirect=1#comment111378147_62983039), be more precise:

```
--after=2020-07-18-00:00:00
```

to force Git to use midnight of the specified date.

Note that `--before`/`--until` and `--after`/`--since` always work with the *committer timestamp*, not the *author timestamp*.  See also [Specification for syntax of git dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14023794/1256452) and [this blog entry at alexpeattie.com](https://alexpeattie.com/blog/working-with-dates-in-git/) as linked from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024118/1256452).  For more background, see [Falsehoods programmers believe about time](https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca).