# How to find all my commits made in last few days?

Tags: git, git-commit

I have been doing

```
git log | grep "chakra" -A3 -B3
```

for each branch separately.

Is there a simple way to find out all the commits a person made.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113425/how-to-make-git-log-show-all-of-todays-commits and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259996/how-can-i-view-a-git-log-of-just-one-users-commits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do

```
git log --author="chakra" --since=4.days --all
```

That will give you your commits on all branches for the last 4 days.

Comment: Remember to specify `--all` to show your recent commits in all branches.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
git log --author="chakra"
```